# Matlab numerical solving of a Second order Ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

On matlab I want to solve *numerically* and plot this ode on $x\in [0,1]$
$$
g''(x)h(x)+g(x)(1-g(x)) = 0
$$
With (assume the 2 conditions) $a,b\in \mathbb R,\ g(0.5)=a$ and $g'(0.5)=b$ and where $h$ is given by
$$
h(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{{-(\phi^{-1}(x)})^2}
$$
and $\phi^{-1}$ is the inverse gaussian cumulative distribution.

On matlab it exists the function *norminv* for $\phi^{-1}$ ([doc](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/norminv.html)).

So I have to solve backwardly and forwardly the ODE (with an euler method for instance).

So as a beginner I have mainly 2 problems :

1. I do not know how to use norminv (which is not a symbolic function) inside *odevectorfield* and *ode45* etc
2. How to tell to matlab to solve the ode backwardly (from $x=0.5$ to $x=0$) and forwardly (from $x=0.5$ to $x=1$)? and plot the final curve ?
3. does my below code is a good way to solve numerically and plot this ODE ? or do I have to use other packages ? dsolve for instance ? If someone has a solution or a code or a closed  example of what I want ?

**my code (is just the idea of the algorithm) that does not work at all is :**

```
syms x,h(x),y(x) 

h(x) := 1./(2.*pi)*exp(-norminv(x)^2)%problem is norminv is not symbolic function

[V] = odeToVectorField(diff(y(x), 2) == y(x)*(y(x)-1.)./h(x)) 

M = matlabFunction(V,'vars', {'x','Y'})

sol = ode45(M,[0 1],[0.5 b]); %on x in[0, 1] and condition is g'(0.5)=b but problem is backwardly and forwardly is not specified to matlab.

plot(sol); %wrong since I have not specified on [0, 1]
```

But it does not work at all.

---

**Extra informations :**

For $\epsilon>0$ small, I have backwardly on from $0.5$ to $0$:
$$
g(x-\epsilon) = g(x) - \epsilon g'(x)\\
g'(x-\epsilon) = g'(x) - \epsilon h^{-1}(x)g(x)(g(x)-1)\\
$$
And forwardly, for $\delta>0$ small from $0.5$ to $1$, 
$$
g(x+\delta) = g(x) + \delta g'(x)\\
g'(x+\delta) = g'(x) + \delta h^{-1}(x)g(x)(g(x)-1)\\
$$

Comment: The conditions $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=1$ hint to this problem being a boundary value problem. ode45 solves initial value problems. Usually you can employ a shooting method and obtain a solution (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method). But here one thing bugs me: If you additionally impose $g'(0.5)=0.9897$ you may have to many conditions and the problem might not be solvable.

Comment: @humanStampedist I have forgotten we know also $g(0.5)=0.3$

Comment: You can't impose more than two boundary/initial conditions, so I do not really understand the setup. Anyway, ode45 doesn't need anything to be symbolic. As for dealing with the fact that your initial condition is in the middle of the domain, the easiest thing is to integrate on [0.5 0] (which ode45 will understand) and [0.5 1] and then stitch the solutions together at the end.

Comment: Instead to use ode45 you need to convert the problem to a first order system by hand and then define your ode function that way. This looks like @(x,y) [y(2);...] where ... expresses the second derivative in terms of x, y (in y(1)) and y' (in y(2)).

Comment: @Ian I think we need initially $g(0.5)$ and $g'(0.5)$. If you think no, why ?

Comment: From the description that sounds right, which means ode45 rather than a BVP solver is suitable.

Comment: @Ian Edit : I have deleted $g(0)$ and $g(1)$ that confuse people on initial conditions

Comment: Your equation is singular at the boundaries $0x=0$ and $x=1$ as $h$ is there zero with zero derivative, additionally, $h$ is not defined outside the interval. Any all-purpose solver will have difficulties handling these singularities.

Comment: Trying with the interval $[0.5, 0.999999]$ to avoid the singularities I get $g(0.999999)\approx 1$ for $g'(0.5)=1.404768$. Where did you get your value from?

Comment: @LutzL Presumably the goal is to find one of the nonsingular solutions with $g(0) \in \{ 0,1 \}$ and $g(1) \in \{ 0,1 \}$, and a nontrivial solution by picking the two to be different. Without the first condition, $g''$ has to blow up very fast in a vicinity of any endpoint that violates that condition. What's not entirely clear to me is if the goal is to actually enforce that, or to use an initial condition that the problem author came up with that already has this property.

Comment: @LutzL my initial values of g(0.5) and g'(0.5) come from another problem (too long to explain). I have put numbers just to illustrate the purpose but they are not the numbers I want to use. I have edited it with a and b. I mainly need help on my matlab code.

Comment: With Mathematica it easy to do, code:`h[x_?NumericQ] := 
  1/(2*Pi)*Exp[-(InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[], x])^2];sol = With[{e = 10^-9}, 
   NDSolve[{g''[x]*h[x] + g[x] (1 - g[x]) == 0, g[1/2] == 3/10, 
     g'[1/2] == 3/2}, g, {x, 0 + e, 1 - e}]];Plot[g[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 1}]` and I have a nice plot.

Comment: @Ian g(0)=0 and g(1)=1 are something we sense that I could get if I apply the good initial conditions(coming from another problem and I do not have the numerics here), So I do never use them (ie g(0) and g(1)) as conditions. I think people has been confused.

Answer (score 2):

One can "unpack" this problem by changing the independent parameter as
$s=\Phi^{-1}(x)$, so that $x=\Phi(s)$ and consequently $h(x)=\frac1{2\pi}e^{-s^2}=\phi(s)^2$ where $\Phi'=\phi$ is the density of the normal distribution.

Computing the derivatives of the reparametrized function
$u(s)=g(\Phi(s))$ gives $u'(s)=g'(\Phi(s))\phi(s)$ and 
$$
u''(s)=g''(\Phi(s))\phi(s)^2+g'(\Phi(s))\phi'(s)
=-u(s)(1-u(s))+u'(s)\frac{\phi'(s)}{\phi(s)}.
$$
or
$$
u''(s)+su'(s)+u(s)(1-u(s))=0.
$$
This now is, in forward direction, a mechanical system with steadily increasing friction and a potential function $\frac12u^2-\frac13u^3$. The steady states resp. extrema of the potential function are a minimum at $u=0$ and a maximum at $u=1$.

Using the energy function 
$$E=\frac12u'^2+\frac12u^2-\frac13u^3,$$

- if the energy at time $s=0$ is smaller than the local maximum $\frac16$ of the potential energy at any position $u$ between $0$ and $1$, the system will fall down into the minimum.
- if the energy is substantially larger than $\frac16$, the solution will move across the maximum and fall down the potential, that is, diverge to $+\infty$.
- for some initial energy in-between, the solution will converge toward the unstable maximum. The solution rapidly has to get to values close to $1$, else the energy bleed-off due to the increasing friction will drive the energy below the level of the local maximum.

As the equation is symmetric about $s=0, u=0.5$ or $x=0.5, y=0.5$, the whole analysis can be extended to the first half of the integration interval by exchanging the role of $u=0$ and $u=1$. Symmetric continuation will give one solution connecting stable to unstable stationary points $u(-\infty)=0$ to $u(\infty)=1$, and many solutions connecting the unstable to stable stationary points $u(-\infty)=1$ to $u(\infty)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is not my mathematical field but it is very interesting and I do not understand how to get the energy function ? What is the purpose of it ?And what is the link with the ode problem ? Or maybe do you have a link summurizing those concepts/calculus ?

Comment: @AlBundy In Hamiltonian dynamics you have equations of the form $u''=-\nabla_u V(u)$, where $V$ is the potential and $\nabla_u$ is the gradient (simply the derivative with respect to $u$ in one dimension). This equation has a constant value of the Hamiltonian $H(u(t))=V(u(t)) + 1/2 u'(t)^2$. You notice that $u'$ does not explicitly appear in the equation here, so you can add in another term to get $u''=-\nabla H(u) + F(s,u')$. This $F$ is usually drag or friction in physics.

Comment: @AlBundy (Cont.) Here, after converting to the $s$ independent variable was to identify the Hamiltonian, which is done by integrating the gradient of the potential and adding in the kinetic energy. Then you look at the equation and see that there's a conservative term and a friction term, so the energy drops. Now you look at the extrema of the potential and you see that there are four of them: $-\infty$ and $1$ (max) and $0$ and $+\infty$ (min). Then the rest is about how the dynamics move you between these. This can be qualitatively understood from the point of view of the energy alone.

Comment: @AlBundy (Cont.)  Basically, if you start in $(-\infty,1)$ then the potential tries to push you towards $0$, but if you start in $(0,1)$ with enough speed then you can surpass the potential and the friction, allowing you to get past the barrier at $1$, at which point the potential now pushes you towards $+\infty$ instead. And if you start in $(0,1)$ with *just* the right speed for where you started, then you can converge exactly to $1$.

Comment: (Hopefully you can extract the intended meaning of the preceding comments despite the several egregious typos...)

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines, as @Ian suggested?

```
function odenorminv
  options = odeset('Stats', 'on', 'maxstep', 0.001);
  g0 = [0.5, 0.5];
  sol = ode45(@f, [0.5, 0.99], g0, options);
  plot(sol.x, sol.y)
  grid on
  legend('g','g''','location','northwest')
end

function ydot = f(x,g)
  ydot = [g(2); -g(1)*(1-g(1))/h(x)];
end

function rv = h(x)
  rv = exp(-norminv(x).^2);
end
```

Comment: Thx your code is very useful now how to automatize if I have on $[0,1]$ 4 intervals for instance $[0,0.25]$, ...,$[0.75,1]$ (could be $n$ intervals) with the associated initial values like $g(0.25)=x_0, g'(0.25)=x'_0$ .... $g(0.75)=x_2, g'(0.75)=x'_2$. I want to solve with ode45 on each intervals and plot the solution. Is there a way to do it with vectors ? 

For instance I give in parameter a matrix $2\times4$ (because 2 conditions and 4 intervals) of initial conditions and a vector $X=linespace(0,1,4)$ (or $n$ for generalizing) (for instance with a loop for) and plot the solution.

Comment: @AlBundy Yes, you can use a for loop, `for n=1:4` and issue a `figure(n)` command before plotting to get a figure at each iteration.  Many variations are possible.

Comment: @AlBundy If you're changing the initial conditions, then you'll need to use a loop, but if you're just trying to ensure that you have a particular time in the solution, you can pass more than two elements in the tspan argument, for example passing in [0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1] will simulate from time 0 to time 1 but it will force the time step routine to include 0.25, 0.5 and 0.75 as intermediate times.